# Sharing image from camera roll with Instagram, Facebook

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have an AR app, developed xcode 9 using ARKit. I have a button which takes a screenshot of the users view and it saves the image done to the photos (camera roll).

I would now like to have a share button and allow the user to share the last image taken stored in the camera role to share it with Facebook, Twitter, Instagram etc.

I assume I use the “UIActivityViewController” function but I’m not sure how to pass the last image taken to be shared with the selected application.

Any thoughts on how to code this?

Answer (score 0):

when you take a screenshot of the screen you can pass the UIImage directly to UIActivityViewController

```
// to create an image from screenshot

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
// to share the image

var imagesToShare = [AnyObject]()
imagesToShare.append(image)

let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imagesToShare , applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks! One question though; how do I get it to share the last picture stored in the camera roll on the phone rather than taking a screenshot of the current frame?